# Dynamically load dropdown menu with date so that it queries database

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I know how to dynamically load a drop-down menu but my question is more around this problem...

I have a table that holds golf scores for players and the date that each player played that scorecard. So there may be for example; 20 scorecards played in 2015, and 20 scorecards played in 2014..what I want to do is dynamically populate the drop-down menu with only one option of 2014 and 2015. At the minute my drop-down is populating with 20 x 2015 and 20 x 2014.

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS Date FROM leaderboard
```

Above is the SQL I am using to get the YEAR from Date in my table. Any suggestions how I could only show 1 option for each year in the drop-down menu?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) AS Date FROM leaderboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html).

`SELECT YEAR(date) AS Date FROM leaderboard GROUP BY YEAR(date)`

Or [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) as B-and-P mentioned:

`SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) AS Date FROM leaderboard`